# Don't bug me about questions needing votes too when I have ~750 question votes and ~840 answer votes

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-experience

Today I happen to vote on a bunch of answers and now I get this message every time I vote on an answer:

> You haven't voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too!

I don't vote a lot, but I do have ~750 question votes and ~840 answer votes. I know how voting works, I don't need a pampering reminder.

Comment: Voting on *one* question will shut it up for a while. Just one. I'm sure it's not that hard to find one crappy question to downvote.

Comment: Go switch to [tag:php]

Comment: I believe this happens when you give "too many" votes to answer consecutively, so the total number of votes don't count (You could have 1000 votes on question and 0 votes on answer, but after X consecutive votes on answers you'd get the message anyway).

Comment: @Bakuriu I know how it works, my point is that I'm not a new user who doesn't know how voting works.

Comment: Because of the mixed response on this, I've gone ahead and written a user script to block this message. I'll put it on BitBucket and StackApps tonight after getting the metadata block set up. (And I'll post here too.)

Comment: OMFG **~750 / ~840** - you _do_ vote on questions indeed. "Mixed response" on this is because 1) you didn't put it into the title and 2) too much meta regulars vote "instinctively", without even reading question text

Comment: You say this, and yet you appear to have not voted on a single question over the course of the last several dozen answer votes, so while you once voted on questions regularly, you appear to have stopped.  Seems like a reminder is appropriate for such a situation.

Comment: @Servy *"Today I happen to vote on a bunch of answers"*

Comment: @gnat hard to judge for myself, but thanks for putting it in the title :)

Comment: @Stijn So why are you unwilling to vote on questions today?  Why did you choose today to only answer questions?  Why is it wrong for the site to remind you that this sudden change in voting patterns isn't great for the site, and that using some votes on questions would be nice?

Comment: @Servy the answers I was voting on were all for the same question, a question which happened to already have more than 1000 votes so I don't think a vote on that question would matter or be useful. The answers I voted on were bad or duplicates and I downvoted them. I vote on content when I see it, I don't go out of my way looking for content to vote on.

Comment: @BoltClock My image on moderators here... just broke to death.

Comment: @Servy anyway, it seems people are not getting my point but perhaps I'm not able to make clear what I mean. When I got that message it felt like the system was talking down to me.

Comment: @Stijn It seems you aren't getting everyone else's point, that the feature is helpful in encouraging beneficial use of the site's features, and the fact that it happened to annoy you once doesn't mean the entire feature should be scrapped entirely.

Comment: You felt "like the system was talking down to me"? I, for one, welcome our new system overlords. ;)

Comment: It is futile to vote questions, they do not need voting at all. The usefulness of a question has to come from answers and their up votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I've created a user script to block this message and I've made a post on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/4861/do-not-bug-me-about-questions-needing-votes-too).

> ## Description
>
> Hide the warning that appears after voting on a certain number of answers without voting on questions inbetween.
>
> ## Installation
>
> https://bitbucket.org/stijnherreman/stack-exchange-user-scripts/raw/default/do-not-bug-me-about-questions-needing-votes-too.user.js
>
> ## Source
>
> https://bitbucket.org/stijnherreman/stack-exchange-user-scripts/src/default/do-not-bug-me-about-questions-needing-votes-too.user.js

Answer (score 3):

I somehow get your point (I think): No damn machine is gonna tell me what to do! ;) However, look that it's not "talking down to you" - it's just stating two simple facts. It's up to you how you'll use that information.

There is nothing wrong with *information* alone, information nowadays is *gold*. Sometimes it may happen, that the *intent* may be bad indeed, however this part needs an accurate guess, and it's very hard. I agree with the others, that it seems that you didn't guess accurately this time - the intent of this message is good ;)

Comment: I agree that the intent of the message is good.  But I think the point of the question is that, based on the number of question votes and answer votes, it should be known that the message is likely to be of no benefit to a particular recipient.